# LTO-8 tapes long-term storage rules

Tags: lto

I have a bunch of tapes LTO-8 written in LTFS by HPE tape-drive. I can not find any rules for reliable physical storage for the tapes. I have an anti-magnetic case for them, but maybe there are some other rules? Should I rewind them in some period of time or I can just put them into the case for 10 years and do nothing?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience (with previous generations, obviously), LTO tapes kept in their boxes in a cool and dry place, written once, are perfectly readable 10 years later without any trouble 98 to 99% of the time.